# Canecelling the Guest Account?

Tags: 12.04

How can I remove the Guest account from my admin account?
Because there is no use of have a password for the admin account will the guest is open to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Open /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file from your terminal using the following command

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following line

```
allow-guest=false
```

Save and exit the file. Restart the machine.

Answer (score 0):

To disable Guest-session have to edit `lightdm.conf`. To do,

open `lightdm.conf` using any text editor like `nano`, `gedit` as follows,

Open terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following command(For 12.04 LTS),

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

For **14.04 LTS**,

```
$ sudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf
```

And make the text as following,

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
allow-guest=false
```

Else simply you can type the following command in terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>),

```
 $ sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -l false
```

It will automatically do the above said in `lightdm.conf`.

**Update**

Also do by opening terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following command,

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "[SeatDefaults]\nallow-guest=false\n" >/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf'
```

Save the file and restart the system.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the command

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
```

Add the following line to that file as last line, save and close.

```
allow-guest=false
```

Reboot and see.